# How do I create a list of ranges in Python?

Tags: python, list, iteration, range

I need to create a list of ranges in Python. The list will contain 100 values over `range(100,5000,100)`. Each element of the list needs to contain 100 values. For example, `L[0]` will be 0 to 100 in increments of 1, 0 - 200 will be in increments of 2, 0 - 5000 will be in increments of 50. I have the following code:

```
K = list(range(100,5000,100))
    L = []
    for i in K:
        Q = list(range(100, i, int(i/100)))
        L.append(Q)
```

This produces `L` with elements that are not all of length 100 and not the desired sequences. I can't seem to figure this out. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the lengths of the lists then, if they are not 100?

Comment: If you have list 0 to 100 the length will be 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a possible solution:

```
n = 100
L = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    l = list(range(0, i * n, i))
    L.append(l)
```

Inspecting the list yields:

```
L[0]
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 100]

L[1]
>> [0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 200]

len(L)
>> 100

len(l)
>> 100
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
l = []
for x in range(1,51):
    l.append([x for x in range(0,x*101,x)])
```

```
l[0]
# [0, 1, ..., 99, 100]

l[49]
# [0, 50, ..., 4950, 5000]
```

These lists have `len` of `101`, adjust it to your needs by changing the `0` or `101` in the range depending on what is relevant to you, either including the `100` or starting from `0`.